# Access denied when running core web api using terminal window

Tags: .net-core, console

When I try to run my dotnet core 3.1 web api using command terminal I'm getting the following error, although, I can run the same api using VS 2019.

```
D:\Workspace\Products\smartShopper\API>dotnet run    
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied.      
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)      
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()     
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()   
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Execute()    
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Run(String[] args)   
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)    
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Until last week I was able to use the same command, but since yesterday when I updated my windows 10 pro, I was no longer able to use it anymore. So, does it due to windows update or any changes in the .net framework core or i am doing any mistake?.

Thanks